# How to create test site structure before each plone.app.robotframework-based test?

Tags: plone, robotframework

I can't find a way to having something like `setUp` and `tearDown` when running a Plone robot test.

What I need is to create a whole site structure before each test. The only way I found is to create my own new robot keyword that create the structure from the browser itself, but I don't want to test the folder creation. This will slow down my tests for nothing.

I found something promising in the robotsuite library: [https://github.com/collective/robotsuite/blob/b52000c65ea96b2be697bf899829c397985fc5aa/src/robotsuite/**init**.py#L217](https://github.com/collective/robotsuite/blob/b52000c65ea96b2be697bf899829c397985fc5aa/src/robotsuite/__init__.py#L217)
However I can't make it works: I can define an empty `setUp` function, with no Plone context.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sry I cannot help you, but can you answer the following question for me: Why are you using robotframework tests? what is the benefit? Background info: We also invested a lot of time in robotframework tests, but the value of the test result was not greater compared to functional tests. So we dropped robotframework tests for our packages and everything still runs fine :-)

Comment: To be honest I have the same doubt and heard some rumors about this :) - however our application contains JavaScript feature we'd like to test. Also: the snapshot feature will help us in the final user documentation. So: for now we'll try this road.

Comment: Well this is the same road as we took :-) Thanks for your answer. Finally we made screenshots manually and tested our js code separately :-) This was much faster and only 1% as complicated as with robotframework tests ;-) good luck, hopefully some one can help you. btw. Timo Stollenwerk could be the right person for you.

Comment: I found the site from the setup argument :) If you have ``def mySetUp(test)``, it's ``test._dt_test.globs['layer']['portal']``. I'll keep in my mind to make it available as ``test.layer['portal']`` when I update ``robotsuite`` next time (I also should add globs-support [similar to DocTestSuite] to inject global robot variables directly from test suite registration).

Comment: Ah! Probably you added this later! Using version 1.3.3 of robotsuite (default on Plone 4.3.3) I can't add any parameter to setUp function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't remember that it's still broken in 1.3.x. I should backport the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you can always define your test site structure in the setup methods of your **plone.app.testing** based test layer. (See docs for [plone.app.testing](http://pypi.pyhon.org/pypi/plone.app.testing) for details.)

In addition to that, there are at least a few ways to build test site structure for **plone.app.robotframework** based Selenium tests:

---

The first is passing your test setUp function as **setUp**-keyword argument for **RobotTestSuite**-class:

```py
import unittest
import robotsuite

from plone.testing import layered
from my.package.testing import MY_PACKAGE_ROBOT_TESTING

from zope.component.hooks import getSite
from transaction import commit


def mySetUp(testCase=None):
    site = getSite()
    # do stuff
    commit()


def test_suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests([
        layered(
            robotsuite.RobotTestSuite('test_something.robot',
                                      setUp=mySetUp),
            layer=MY_PACKAGE_ROBOT_TESTING
        ),
    ])
    return suite
```

There should be no need for explicit tearDown, because plone.app.testing's functional test teardown already reverts all changes made to the test sandbox.

This feature is based on **RobotTestSuite** built to mimic DocTestSuite from doctest-module. The setUp-method takes a single argument, the test case object, but because the test layer is lost somewhere in the test framework, **getSite** is the only sane way to reach the portal object.

Finally, it's good to know that this approach works only as long as the Robot Framework test is executed within the same process where Plone test layer is built (which is the case when executing **robosuite**-wrapped test suites with e.g. **zope.testrunner**).

---

The second way would be to split the **setUp** function into a custom local python keyword library. For example, in `my/package/testing.py` you could have:

```py
from plone import api
from transaction import commit


class MyPackageKeywords(object):

    def create_stuff(self, stuff_id):
        portal = api.portal.get()
        obj = api.content.create(
            type='Document',
            title='My Stuff',
            container=portal
        )
        commit()
        return obj.absolute_url()
```

And you should be able to use it like:

```
*** Settings ***
...
Library  my.package.testing.MyPackageKeywords

*** Test Cases ***
...
    ${URL} =  Create stuff  stuff_id=my-stuff
    Go to  ${URL}
    Element should contain  css=h1.documentFirstHeading  My Stuff
```

This has the same limitation as the first approach.

---

The third possible way is to create the content in the actual Robot Framework test suites by using the content related remote keywords provided in the recent **plone.app.robotframework** releases.

In short, this is done by including **REMOTE_LIBRARY_BUNDLE_FIXTURE** in your test layer and using its **Create content** and **Fire transition** keywords for creating the required mock content.

```py
import unittest
import robotsuite

from plone.app.robotframework.testing import REMOTE_LIBRARY_BUNDLE_FIXTURE
from plone.app.testing import PLONE_FIXTURE
from plone.testing import layered
from plone.testing import z2


PLONE_ACCEPTANCE_TESTING = z2.FunctionalTesting(
    bases=(REMOTE_LIBRARY_BUNDLE_FIXTURE,
           PLONE_FIXTURE,
           z2.ZSERVER_FIXTURE),
    name="Acceptance")


def test_suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests([
        layered(
            robotsuite.RobotTestSuite('test_something.robot'),
            layer=PLONE_ACCEPTANCE_TESTING
        ),
    ])
    return suite
```

```
*** Settings ***

Resource  plone/app/robotframework/keywords.robot
Resource  Selenium2Screenshots/keywords.robot

Library  Remote  ${PLONE_URL}/RobotRemote

Test Setup  Open test browser
Test Teardown  Close all browsers

*** Test Cases ***

Scenario: View folder contents
    Given a contributor
      and a folder
      and a document inside the folder
     when at the folder listing
     then can see the document title

*** Variables ***

${FOLDER_ID}  a-folder
${DOCUMENT_ID}  a-document

*** Keywords ***

A contributor
    Enable autologin as  Contributor

A folder
    Create content  type=Folder
    ...  id=${FOLDER_ID}
    ...  title=A folder
    ...  description=This is the folder

A document inside the folder
    Create content  type=Document
    ...  container=/${PLONE_SITE_ID}/${FOLDER_ID}
    ...  id=${DOCUMENT_ID}
    ...  title=A document
    ...  description=This is the document
    ...  text=<p><strong>Hello world!</strong></p>

At the folder listing
    Go to  ${PLONE_URL}/${FOLDER_ID}/folder_contents
    Element should be visible  name=folderContentsForm

Can see the document title
    Page should contain  A document
    Capture and crop page screenshot  folder-contents.png  css=#content
```

Plese note, that **Create content** -keyword may also require use of **Enable autologin as** -keyword to authenticate the content creation calls. Also note, that **Capture and crop page screenshot** is nowadays in a separate package **robotframework-selenium2screenshots**.

Content creation keywords are not yet perfect and issues may be reported at [GitHub](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.robotframework). You can also implement your own [remote python keywords](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.robotframework/docs/source/robot.html#remote-keyword-libraries). They are just methods in simple python classes, which is wrapped into [REMOTE_LIBRARY_BUNDLE_FIXTURE](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.robotframework/blob/master/src/plone/app/robotframework/testing.py#L102).

Finally, see also [the good known versions for plone.app.robotframework and friends](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plone/plone.app.robotframework/master/versions.cfg).

Comment: I like the first answer approach, hope to find some time to test this tomorrow, it was exacly what I've tried but simply didn't think about using the `getSite` to obtain a Plone context... :-(

The `commit` usage is something I don't fully understand.

Comment: The commit usage is similar to what you have to do with zope.testbrowser-based tests. ZODB provides "multiversion concurrency control", so the only way to make your changes visible to the browser is to commit them. (The explicit commit is not required in test layer's setupPloneSite, because PloneSandboxLayer has implicit commit after calling the setup methods.)

Comment: The reason for the second approach is to support fast **robot-server**-approach for writing the tests: there the test layer is set up only once for the whole test writing session with ``bin/robot-server`` and individual ``.robot``-suites are run in separate processes by calling ``bin/robot`` for them (it adds some default settings for ``pybot`` call to enable test isolation). This approach is described in http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.robotframework/docs/source/happy.html

Comment: Yeah, it works! BTW: probably this very detailed commento must be added somewhere to the Plone documentation!
Thanks!